# Org-mode: Filter on tag in agenda view?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to filter on tags when agenda constructs its view? I have tried the following to show only work related appointments:

```lisp
("j" "Jobb"
   ((agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp":jobb:"))))
    (tags-todo "jobb"))
    ((org-agenda-compact-blocks nil)))
```

This works only if the actual appointment is directly tagged, but not if the appointment inherits its tag from a parent headline like this:

```
 * Tider                                                              :jobb:                                                                                                                                                         
 ** Millas arbetstider                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   <2012-04-11 ons 05:00-09:00>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   <2012-04-12 tor 04:15-08:30>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   <2012-04-13 fre 14:30-18:30>
```

Is there another way to do this so that appointments that inherits its tag shows up?

Comment: Jobb is Swedish for work btw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is in how `org-agenda-skip-entries-if` interacts with `'notregexp`.  It will skip any entries that do not match `:jobb:`. Even though the later entries inherit the tag, it is not explicitly listed and so they are skipped.  There also does not seem to be any built-in method to match (or not match) on tags using `org-agenda-skip-entries-if`.  If there is such a function it would likely be the more efficient method of looking for the tags, but I'm not aware of such a function.

You instead have to create a custom function that will provide the desired search-format.

If you change your agenda command to:

```lisp
("j" "Jobb"
         ((agenda ""
                  ((org-agenda-skip-function '(zin/org-agenda-skip-tag "jobb" 't))))
          (tags-todo "jobb"))
         ((org-agenda-compact-blocks nil)))
```

and define `zin/org-agenda-skip-tag` as:

```lisp
(defun zin/org-agenda-skip-tag (tag &optional others)
  "Skip all entries that correspond to TAG.

If OTHERS is true, skip all entries that do not correspond to TAG."
  (let ((next-headline (save-excursion (or (outline-next-heading) (point-max))))
        (current-headline (or (and (org-at-heading-p)
                                   (point))
                              (save-excursion (org-back-to-heading)))))
    (if others
        (if (not (member tag (org-get-tags-at current-headline)))
            next-headline
          nil)
      (if (member tag (org-get-tags-at current-headline))
          next-headline
        nil))))
```

You will get what I understand to be your desired agenda view.  If I have it backwards and the entries on the next 3 days should not be present, you simply have to change the function to `(zin/org-agenda-skip-tag "jobb")` or `(zin/org-agenda-skip-tag "jobb" 'nil)`, they are equivalent in this case.

#### Agenda View

In this case `test-new` is the name of the org-file I was using, it can be ignored.  I also set both headlines to `TODO` to have them visible when testing the function, since I was restricting the agenda to only the one file.

```
Week-agenda (W15):
Monday      9 April 2012 W15
Tuesday    10 April 2012
Wednesday  11 April 2012
  test-new:    5:00- 9:00 TODO Millas arbetstider                        :jobb::
Thursday   12 April 2012
  test-new:    4:15- 8:30 TODO Millas arbetstider                        :jobb::
Friday     13 April 2012
  test-new:   14:30-18:30 TODO Millas arbetstider                        :jobb::
Saturday   14 April 2012
Sunday     15 April 2012

================================================================================
Headlines with TAGS match: jobb
  test-new:   TODO Tider                                                  :jobb:
  test-new:   TODO Millas arbetstider                                    :jobb::
```

Comment: This was not what I was after, this doesn't make the agenda part of the block ignore all appointments not tagged with with "jobb"

Comment: Oops, I misinterpreted your question (looking back it was clear, I just didn't read properly).  I'll edit to provide an answer that does do what you want (or seems to based on your example).

Comment: I'm getting 't from org-back-to-heading, so I had to replace the let of current-headline with 
(save-excursion (progn (org-back-to-heading) (point)))

Comment: Hrm, it only does that if the scan is initiated from on the headline, if you're on any other line it will succeed.  I'll edit the code to include a check for that case (which in this context will only occur with timestamps in the headline).

Comment: This seems to work, but is there any way to combine this with a standard `org-agenda-skip-subtree-if`?

Comment: Figured it out - just use `or`. For example `(or (zin/org-agenda-skip-tag "jobb") (org-agenda-skip-subtree-if CONDITIONS))`

Answer (score 5):

After using the function in Jonathan's answer for several months to do this kind of per-block filtering, I found myself wanting something capable of dealing with more sophisticated queries (like the match strings used by the other block types), and I figured I'd post it here for anyone who stumbles across this question in the future.

EDIT: The original implementation of `my/org-match-at-point-p` is now somewhat out of date.  The Org mode sources are now lexically scoped, which changes the contract of `org-make-tags-matcher`.  It used to be that the `todo` and `tags-list` variables needed to be dynamically scoped around the call to `org-make-tags-matcher`, whereas now they seem to be passed to the function returned from the call.  (Yay!  This is so much better!)  I've adapted the code below to match the new version, but I don't use Org mode much anymore, so it's only been lightly tested.

```el
(defun my/org-match-at-point-p (match)
  "Return non-nil if headline at point matches MATCH.
Here MATCH is a match string of the same format used by
`org-tags-view'."
  (funcall (cdr (org-make-tags-matcher match))
           (org-get-todo-state)
           (org-get-tags-at)
           (org-reduced-level (org-current-level))))

(defun my/org-agenda-skip-without-match (match)
  "Skip current headline unless it matches MATCH.

Return nil if headline containing point matches MATCH (which
should be a match string of the same format used by
`org-tags-view').  If headline does not match, return the
position of the next headline in current buffer.

Intended for use with `org-agenda-skip-function', where this will
skip exactly those headlines that do not match." 
  (save-excursion
    (unless (org-at-heading-p) (org-back-to-heading)) 
    (let ((next-headline (save-excursion
                           (or (outline-next-heading) (point-max)))))
      (if (my/org-match-at-point-p match) nil next-headline))))
```

In case you're still using the older version of Org mode, here is the original code.  Note that this version assumes that the file in which `my/org-match-at-point-p` is defined is lexically scoped; if not, you can safely replace the `my/defun-dyn` macro with a simple `defun`.

```el
(defmacro my/defun-dyn (&rest def)
  "As `defun', but always in dynamic scope.
A function defined in this way ignores the value of
`lexical-binding' and treats it as if it were nil.

\(fn NAME ARGLIST &optional DOCSTRING DECL &rest BODY)"
  (declare (debug defun)
           (indent defun)
           (doc-string 3))
  `(eval '(defun ,@def) nil))

(my/defun-dyn my/org-match-at-point-p (match &optional todo-only)
  "Return non-nil if headline at point matches MATCH.
Here MATCH is a match string of the same format used by
`org-tags-view'.

If the optional argument TODO-ONLY is non-nil, do not declare a
match unless headline at point is a todo item."
  (let ((todo      (org-get-todo-state))
        (tags-list (org-get-tags-at)))
    (eval (cdr (org-make-tags-matcher match)))))
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your function `my/org-match-at-point`, and I'm having a hard time understanding where `todo-only` comes in. Looking through the `org-make-tags-matcher` documentation, the matcher is supposed to be called with three arguments, and looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757050/800892) implementation of `org-tags-matcher`, its call was done with `todo-only`, while yours isn't. What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like my code is just really out of date.  The Org mode sources are now lexically-scoped, and in order to make `org-make-tags-matcher` work with that, the contract for the the matcher must have been changed.  I'll update the answer with an explanation.

Comment: As for `todo-only`, my recollection is that that used to be another variable that could be dynamically scoped around the call to change the behavior of the matcher (so my declaration in the argument list was sufficient), but that seems to have been removed.  I think the match string syntax may have been augmented instead; the manual mentions a `!` operator that I don't recognize.

Comment: oh, hey! thank you so much. this has given me a couple of pointers that I'll need to pursue later on.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to filter the [Agenda Dispatcher](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Dispatcher.html#Agenda-Dispatcher) by hitting "/" in the agenda view.

> "/" = 
>   Search for a regular expression in all agenda files and additionally
>   in the files listed in org-agenda-text-search-extra-files. This uses
>   the Emacs command multi-occur. A prefix argument can be used to
>   specify the number of context lines for each match...

Comment: can you provide more information? also, add appropriate tags.