# Organizing notes with tags in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

So, I use org-mode extensively for my daily TODO requirements. I am wondering if I can also use it effectively for note keeping. What I basically want is to store notes with tags, and then want to search these notes by the tags. E.g. If I have something like this

```
* Heading 1
** Note 1 :tag1:tag2:
Note 1 details
** Note 2 :tag3:
Note 2 details
* Heading 2
** Note 3
** Note 4 :tag1:
Note 4 details
```

and then I search for tag1, I should have something like-

```
* Heading 1
** Note 1 :tag1:tag2:
Note 1 details
* Heading 2
** Note 4 :tag1:
Note 4 details
```

I would prefer being able to do this without adding the files to my agenda. (I may have several of these notes, and I would only want to search the current file at a time.)

Is there an easy (or not so easy) way to accomplish this org-mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following function should provide the result you want.

```lisp
(defun zin/org-tag-match-context (&optional todo-only match)
  "Identical search to `org-match-sparse-tree', but shows the content of the matches."
  (interactive "P")
  (org-prepare-agenda-buffers (list (current-buffer)))
  (org-overview) 
  (org-remove-occur-highlights) 
  (org-scan-tags '(progn (org-show-entry) 
                         (org-show-context)) 
                 (cdr (org-make-tags-matcher match)) todo-only))
```

Comment: I want to do this! How do I do this? I copy and paste the code segment to my `.emacs` file. Start a new Emacs session. Open an *.org file. Tag headings (with `C-c C-q`). And then what? How do I retrieve all list items with a certain tag?

Comment: Note that `org-prepare-agenda-buffers` has been renamed to `org-agenda-prepare-buffers`. @Chernoff if you are still looking to do this, then you can c&p, replace the old function name, and call it with `M-x zin/org-tag-match-context`

Answer (score 9):

You can use a tag search (`C-c / m tag1 <ret>`). Documentation here:

http://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-searches.html

This will create a sparse tree showing only the headings containing `:tag1:`, but it will not automatically reveal the contents of that heading as in your example.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Do you have any idea of how I might go about trying to expand the headings too? I don't mind doing some programming to get the job done.